# get point after submit Story

Tags: laravel, mongodb, point

how to add points after submitting a post ?

This is my Controller :

```
public function store(PostRequest $request)
{
   $story = Auth::user()->post()->create($request->all());
   $image = $request->File('image');
   if ($image) {
       $image_name = time().'.'.$image->getClientOriginalExtension();
       $destinationPath = public_path('upload');
       $image->move($destinationPath, $image_name);

       $story->image = $image_name;
   }
   $story->update();
   if ($story) {
     flash()->success('Your Story Has Been successfully added');
   }
   return redirect()->back();
}
```

This is my table users :

```
protected $fillable = [
    'name', 'email', 'password', 'point'
];
```

This is my table post story :

```
 protected $fillable = [
     'user_id','title','description','image'
```

];

Comment: how and what basis you are trying to add point?

Comment: is point an integer value? can it increment in the future?

Comment: @DinoNumić yes, this integer value and can it increment in the future

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is up to you to implement the logic of when you increment the point field but here is how you can.

```
$story->increment('point');
```

Or

```
$story->point++;
```

And of course `$story->save();`